# Autoscroll chat without javascript (html and css only)

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, autoscroll

I searched very long time how to autoscroll chat without JavaScript. But couldn't find any solution except this example, but there the scroll with mouse does not work as expected. Anyway all the others uses `JavaScript` more or less. But after some time I saw at an employee one a strange (because I don't clearly understand why it works) but simple solution and I want to share it with SO community. May be someone also search how to auto scroll only with `CSS` properties and `HTML`.

Comment: without `js` is *beyond the bounds of possibility.*

Comment: @Neptotech-vishnu did you run my own answer?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance You are probably right I should add more details about meaning of autoscroll. But my question does not depend on external link, I just share this link to show community that there was some bad solutions which doesn't acceptable to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "magic" part is in the `.messages-wrapper`. All we need in generally is just wrap our `.messages` to another `div` and set to it `flex-direction: column-reverse`. Also we can control from where messages will start from top or from bottom just adding/removing `height: 100%` property to `.messages-wrapper`. The part which I don't understand is why the `column-reverse` works? I always saw that `column-reverse` reverse only first level children order but in this case it do some "magic". I will very glad if someone explains me how and why it works

```js
//JUST TO ADD MESSAGES DYNAMICALLY

const topMessages = document.querySelector('.start-from-top .messages');
const bottomMessages = document.querySelector('.start-from-bottom .messages');

let topMessagesNumber = 0;
let bottomMessagesNumber = 0;

const addMessage = (messages, number) => {
  const message = document.createElement('div');
  message.innerHTML = 'Some text ' + number;
  message.className = 'message';

  const isRightMessage = Math.random() >= 0.5;

  message.classList.add(`${isRightMessage ? 'right' : 'left'}`);
  
  messages.append(message);
}

const addTopMessage = () => {
  addMessage(topMessages, ++topMessagesNumber);
}

const addBottomMessage = () => {
  addMessage(bottomMessages, ++bottomMessagesNumber);
}
```

```css
div:not(.messages):not(.messages-wrapper) {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.chat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 150px;
}

.messages-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.messages-wrapper.start-from-bottom {
  height: 100%;
}

.message {
  margin: 16px 8px;
}

.message.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.message.left {
  text-align: left;
}

.add-message {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
Starting first message from top
<div class="chat">
  <div class="messages-wrapper start-from-top">
    <div class="messages"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="add-message">
    <button onclick="addTopMessage()">Add message</button>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>

Starting first message from bottom
<div class="chat">
  <div class="messages-wrapper start-from-bottom">
    <div class="messages"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="add-message">
    <button onclick="addBottomMessage()">Add message</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in both divisions, after adding 20 messages, **if I scroll up, and then click the `add message` button** *it doesn't auto-scroll*

Comment: @Neptotech-vishnu I know and this is correct, we don't need to scroll down automatically when somebody write when we read old messages. We need to autoscroll when we already in the bottom of chat and wait new mesages

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: This solution doesn't work for iOS; the viewport remains anchored to the last message, it doesn't autoscroll